# is @EnableFeignClients @EnableCircuitBreaker conflict

Tags: spring-cloud, hystrix, spring-cloud-feign

I configured springboot application with

```
@EnableFeignClients
@SpringCloudApplication
```

and get error

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/netflix/hystrix/contrib/javanica/aop/aspectj/HystrixCommandAspect

But if I change annotation to

```
@EnableFeignClients
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
```

which means removed annotation `@EnableCircuitBreaker`

the server start is successful.  Why is `@EnableFeignClients` in conflict with `@EnableCircuitBreaker` ? Or how has the error happened?

Comment: What version are you using? Older versions of spring-cloud-netflix using feign required hystrix. Adding spring-cloud-starter-hystrix probably will fix your issue, or upgrade to Dalston.SR3.

Comment: @spencergibb spring-cloud version is Dalston.SR3 with springboot 1.5.7.RELEASE

Comment: Without Hystrix, the spring cloud application annotation won't work, and you'll get that error